# How do I stream pdf online

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using itextSharp to generate a pdf document this is how I'am saving my pdf:
`string file = "C:/MyDoc/FileName.pdf";`. If I run this program over the network then file path can vary. After doing a lot of research I have found out that I can do this:

```
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + "filename=FileName.pdf");
            Response.Write(document);

              Response.OutputStream.Flush();
             Response.OutputStream.Close();
```

The question is that how would I declare `string file` in above code. The reason for doing this is because later on I am inserting page numbers to the pdf where file variable is passed on e.g.

Comment: you don't show anything in there that requires a physical file; does it work if you use `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream` ?

Comment: BTW; you're currently saving *on the server*; that is a really bad idea

Answer (score 4):

Nothing in there would seem to depend on the existence of a physical file. It seems to me that you should be able to create a `MemoryStream`, use that in place of the `MemoryStream`, and then later write the contents of the `MemoryStream` to the response. In some cases, you can even write directly to the `.OutputStream` (avoiding the `MemoryStream`), but that depends a bit on whether it needs to seek etc. But let's assume we have to buffer:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    CreatePdf(ms); // uses this stream instead of new FileStream(...)

    // not shown: set response headers
    var data = ms.GetBuffer();
    Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, (int)ms.Length);
}
```

Comment: Marc, great answer overall. iTextSharp writes to anything that subclasses `Stream` so both `MemoryStream` and the `Response.OutputStream` although I strongly discourage the latter since it makes debugging harder (error messages sent with PDF content types). Also, instead of `GetBuffer()`, in those context `ToArray()` should be used since the former can return allocated but unused bytes.

Comment: I get few errors `the name CreatePDF does not exist in the current context` and how what do i do with variable file `PdfCopy copyPdf = new PdfCopy(copyDoc, new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create));`

Comment: @user3820587 `CreatePdf` was meant to be a place-holder for all your code that creates the PDF; you don't show how that code is laid out, so I can only give broad suggestions. The rest of the creation code stays the same, except that line you paste becomes: `PdfCopy copyPdf = new PdfCopy(copyDoc, theStreamParameter);`

Comment: I am a bit new to itextsharp I have shown my code under EDIT section. Can i find out how would i trailered toward my example?, as you can see I have added everything under one method just to keep things simple

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to expand upon Marc's answer. `PdfWriter` and `PdfStamper` both use the abstract class `System.IO.Stream`. The example that you posted used both a `System.IO.FileStream` as well as a `System.Web.HttpResponse.OutputStream`, both of which subclass `System.IO.Stream`. Those two are absolutely valid however they are kind of final and specialized. There's another subclass that is less final in that it works in-memory, and that's `System.IO.MemoryStream`.

You can bind a `PdfWriter` to a `MemoryStream`, do all of your work and then say "give me a byte array that represents the PDF". Then, the `PdfReader` has a constructor overload that takes a byte array, so you can just pass your bytes right back into that. So instead of `new PdfReader(filepath)` you can say `new PdfReader(bytes)`.

I encourage you to use this pattern whenever you work with PDFs:

1. Create a `MemoryStream`
2. Create a PDF using that stream
3. Grab the raw bytes when done
4. Do something with the bytes. Write to disk, send to `HttpResponse`, send back to step #2, etc.

The advantage of the first three steps is that you don't have to think about file paths or even ASP.Net itself. That code is 100% portable from desktop to server. The fourth step is the only that's really specific to a situation and is really "okay, I've made a PDF, now what do I want to do with it?"

See the code and comments below for a sample that shows this off:

```
//Instead of writing to a file, we're going to just keep a byte array around
//that we can work with and/or write to something else

//At the start, this array is not initialized to anything
Byte[] bytes;

//Create a very basic PDF using a MemoryStream
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)) {
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
    //When the "PDF stuff" is done but before we dispose of the MemoryStream, grab the raw bytes
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}



//At this exact point, the variable "bytes" is an array of bytes that
//represents a PDF. This could be sent to the browser via Response.BinaryWrite(bytes).
//It could also be written to disk using System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(myFilePath, bytes).
//It could also be read back into a PdfReader directly via the code below

//Create a new PDF based on the old PDF
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    //Bind a reader to our previously created array
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(bytes)) {
        //Very simple stamper, could be much more complex, just draws a rectangle
        using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
            var cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

            cb.Rectangle(50, 50, 200, 200);
            cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
            cb.Fill();
        }
    }
    //Once again, grab the bytes before closing the MemoryStream but after the "PDF stuff"
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

//Once again, the "bytes" variable represents a PDF at this point
//The above can be repeated as many times as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with generating files Word/PDF myself. These generates do not work with relative paths. My solution was as follows (In VBA, but it should be similar in C#):

Create a fileinfo

```
Dim getInfo As System.IO.FileInfo
```

Fill the fileinfo with a (Relative) path of the file you need:

```
getInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("Pathname")
```

Use the fileinfo to get the full absolute path instead of the relative path (getInfo.FullName).

```
PdfCopy copyPdf = new PdfCopy(copyDoc, new FileStream(getInfo.FullName, FileMode.Create));
```